# Semantic Ui Accordion get number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm using a Semantic Ui accordion and want the user to be able to print the accordion with all elements. (It's like a FAQ accordion)
Is there a way to open all accordion elements or get the index of the last element?
Here is my javascript code:

```
$('.print-btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.ui.accordion').accordion('open', 0);;
    setTimeout(function() { //wait a second until the accordion is opened
        print();
    }, 1000);
});
```

This would open the first element and then print it. So I practically need a loop to open all elements and for that I need the number of elements.
I don't know the number of elements beforehand, because the data can change through the database.

Comment: You may want to look into the 'css print media query' (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). That allows you to have css for print only. In that specific css you could have all the accordions open all the time. You should not need any javascript to do this.

Comment: I thought about that, but it's not that easy with the semantic-ui accordion than expected. I think it's "better" to get it done with javascript.

Comment: It's definitely not "better" but it might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark all your FAQ items with a specific class and get all items with the specified class selector (I use *jQuery* here):

```
var items = $('.faq-item.ui.accordion');
```

After that it's trivial to go through each item from the array `items` and *open* them with a `for-loop`:

```
for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  items.accordion('open', i)
});
```

Comment: This worked flawless. Easier than expected... Thank you!